# Fix ESLint no-plusplus and no-param-reassign linter errors when adding to accumulator in reduce function

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

Give this code in TypeScript:

```js
const res = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => (cur.id ? ++acc : acc), 0);
```

How do I stop the linter throwing these two errors?

> (parameter) acc: number Unary operator '++' used. eslint no-plusplus

> Assignment to function parameter 'acc'. eslint no-param-reassign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) callback accepts an accumulator and the current value as arguments and returns the accumulator for the next iteration, or the accumulator as a result if there is no next iteration. There is no reason to *mutate* any of the arguments.

There are [a few arguments in favor of avoiding mutating parameters *in general*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28792326/4642212), and that’s why ESLint complains about this, with the [`no-param-reassign` rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign).

The [`no-plusplus` rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-plusplus), additionally, disallows syntax like `++acc`.

Since there is no need to mutate `acc` to begin with, the minimal fix for *both* errors would be:

```js
   const res = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => (cur.id ? acc + 1 : acc), 0);
//                                                ~~~~^~~              Replace `++acc` by `acc + 1`
```

This returns `acc` incremented by `1` if `cur.id` is truthy, and the current `acc`, otherwise, *as expected*. Your version mutates the current `acc` in addition to returning the incremented `acc`, but there is no reason to do so.

---

If you’re using ESLint, you have to be aware of the rules. You can’t write code that ESLint complains about and then be confused why ESLint complains about your code. [Every rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules) has its own article explaining the rationale, listing alternatives, and explaining how the rule can be adjusted or disabled.

For example, you can disable the `no-param-reassign` rule

- by including the comment `// eslint-disable no-param-reassign` at the top of your file,
- or `// eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign` one line above a usage,
- or `// eslint-disable-line no-param-reassign` in the line after a usage,
- or by disabling it in your `.eslintrc` file.

---

There’s also [a rule that would disallow conditional expressions](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-ternary) and some [variants](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unneeded-ternary). You can further simplify your function to avoid even that:

```js
const res = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + Number(Boolean(cur.id)), 0);
```

This would have the same semantics, but it’s still not quite clear what kind of condition `cur.id` was supposed to be. It’s best practice to make that a little more explicit (especially in TypeScript), e.g. `cur.hasOwnProperty("id")` or `cur.id !== 0` or `cur.id !== ""`, depending on what `cur.id` may be. Then, the `Boolean` call is no longer necessary; for example, if you want to count how many objects in `arr` have an `id` own property, use this instead:

```js
const res = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + Number(cur.hasOwnProperty("id")), 0);
```

or this:

```js
const res = arr.filter((cur) => cur.hasOwnProperty("id")).length;
```

If you still want to use your original [falsy / truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) check, the code can be shortened to one of these, using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
const res = arr.reduce((acc, {id}) => acc + Number(Boolean(id)), 0);
```

```js
const res = arr.filter(({id}) => id).length;
```