# strange javascript variable re assignment issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a variable called `data`, which brings an array to a function.

I then decided to continue using only the first element of the array (`data[0]`). would it have any difference if I do either of the following?

1. reuse/replace the array variable name `data` by assigning it with its first element, which would be

    `data = data[0]`

   and continue to use `data`
2. declare a new variable and assign it the first element of the array data, which would be

    `var data_new = data[0]`

Is there any problem in doing the first one? is there any case that I should strictly use the second one instead of the first one?

**I am asking this because I had a strange problem related to this**, when I got a data from a fetch request and it made a difference when I used the first method and the second method.

```
fetch("some json array returning url").then(response=>{
    response.json().then(data => {
    
        data = data[0]
        setState(data);
        return;
        
        // Vs           

        var data2 = data[0]
        setState(data2);
        return;
        
        //based on which is uncommented

    }
}
```

On my first block (using same variable `data`), the result was randomly changing. but when I used the second block, It became stable and predictable.

To be more specific on the results, for data that as the form ["data"], when using the first block, the result fluctuates between "data" and "d", where as while using the second block, it always returns "data"

Sorry for I can't put a fully reproducible example, But It would really help me out if there is any possible reason to prefer one over the other according to javascript language, based on the above simple use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you don't want to be mutating the parameters of a function. Doing `data = data[0]` may cause bugs later on. It is better to create a new variable and make changes to that one, as with `var data2 = data[0]`.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see any problems with both of them, but in the 1st method it can make code more confusing to read because the variables have different types in different places. I would prefer solution 2

Comment: Try not to change the type of the variable in the code, and don't change parameters taken from functions. Do ```var modifiedStuff = parameterThing ``` Makes it more consistent.