# assign value to function parameter, is it safe to reuse function arguments?

Tags: javascript

Is it a bad practice to reuse function parameter variables?

```
const reformat = (phone)=>{
    phone = phone.replace("-", ",")

    //... more operation using phone

    return phone;
}
```

is there any reason such reusage should be avoided? or is it always safe to continue such usage?

Comment: depending on what you need to do, regarding to the function argument types

Comment: [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Comment: @Andy there are more operations in between.

Comment: @MisterJojo, Is there any case this could be dangerous? on any argument type in javascript?

Comment: That variable is declared by and exists only within that function, I see no reason why that function can't assign values to it as it sees fit.  Whether or not this makes the intent of the code less clear is a matter of opinion.

Comment: dangerous ? somebody could be killed ?

Comment: @MisterJojo,  I won't be using it for the surgery robot I am writing in javascript. I meant unexpected results...

Comment: @David, It's because I am still puzzled by a random error here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68644126/strange-javascript-variable-re-assignment-issue still traumatized by that, not to reassign value to parameters

Comment: @David, But Both are assigning `data[0]` to the holder variable

Comment: @Abraham: In that other example the re-use of the same variable definitely made the code confusing at a glance.  But without a more complete example demonstrating the problem, one might only be able to guess.  A [mcve] would really help here.  Because it sounds like *this* question is based mostly on assumptions resulting from that question, rather than specific debugging observations.

Comment: @David Ok, Thank you. I should improve that. But beyond the confusion, based on your current understanding, they should bring the same result, right?

Comment: @Abraham: Unless you have an example demonstrating otherwise, [yes](https://jsfiddle.net/9mr7j52d/).

Comment: Thank you, I will improve those

Answer (score 1):

For strings, like in your example, it's fine. Some people may think it could get confusing if you're trying to debug and log that variable to the console sometime after it's been changed, but that's mostly subjective. Use your best judgement.

For objects, which are always passed by reference, you should avoid making changes in the function because those changes will still be present outside the function as well.

E.G.:

```js
var myObject = {
  message: "Hello, world"
};

function alertMessage(msgObj){
  msgObj.message = "Hello moto";
  alert(msgObj.message);
}

alertMessage(myObject);

// The object has changed.
console.log(myObject);
```

Comment: how about total reasignment, would that be always safe?

Comment: reassigning the variable name to something completely different will cause you to completely lose the reference to whatever was originally assigned to that variable name, but it will not change the variable outside of the function. Really depends on what you consider "safe."

Comment: Yes, I agree it could be confusing. But logically, it shouldn't make any different result, right?

Comment: Completely reassigning the variable will not make any difference outside the function, no. But any modifications of any objects or anything that inherits from an object (like an Array), will make a difference outside of the function.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not. And it's memory saving sometimes, since when you use another new variable, it will take up your memory. And the function process is much longer many transformations then it will be not a good practice to do. So according to your questions,

1. Yes, you can use the same variable inside the function (But make sure to consider what are the types that you refer when passing as arguments)
2. Re-usage should be avoided when you are using a object and that will change the content of the origin object.

Comment: incase of an object, if you modify its content like `objectVar.name = "name"`, it could affect the others. But what if you do a total reassignment like `objectVar = {name:"name"}` why would it be a problem?

Comment: Total reassignment will not affect to the original object @Abraham. Only the properties reassignment will affect.

Answer (score 1):

different cases to take care:

```js
// argument is not a reference ( string, numbers )
function add_5(num)
  {
  num += 5
  return num
  }

let initial_num = 10
let returned_num = add_5(initial_num )
 
console.log( `initial_num-> ${initial_num}, returned_num-> ${returned_num}`)


// argument is  reference ( objects )
function directArgObj( obj)
  {
  obj.num += 5
  }

let initial_obj = { num: 10, abc:'xyz' }

directArgObj(initial_obj )

console.log( `initial_obj-> ${JSON.stringify(initial_obj)} `)
```